# Help Defining RegEx to Capture Line Definition from INI file

Tags: .net, vb.net, regex

Need help defining an expression to capture the four numerics per line that define the lines on a map.

```
59.684 -4.251 59.575 -5.576
59.575 -5.576 59.437 -6.899
59.437 -6.899 59.27 -8.218
-7.346 23.196 -7.409 23.233
-7.409 23.233 -7.46 23.285
-7.46 23.285 -7.495 23.349
-7.495 23.349 -7.51 23.42
9.172 39.362 9.134 39
9.134 39.288 9.087 39.219
9.087 39.219 9.032 39.155
9.032 39.155 8.97 39.099
8.97 39.099 8.901 39
```

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regex.matches` with the string `"(\S*[\d\.]+)"` iterate through the returned `MatchColection` and the value will have the string you want.

Comment: To capture all four entries on the line I edited yours to this. (\S*[\d\.]+)\s{1,3}(\S*[\d\.]+)\s{1,3}(\S*[\d\.]+)\s{1,3}(\S*[\d\.]+)\b"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<column1>\S+) (?<column2>\S+) (?<column3>\S+) (?<column4>\S+)
```

You can run that expression on every line and it will extract the values between spaces into four named capturing groups.

The `<columnN>` parts are the names of the groups you're capturing. You refer to them as `column1`, `column2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions for that. Untested:

```
Using sr As New StreamReader("myFile.txt")
    Do
        Dim line = sr.ReadLine()
        If line Is Nothing Then Exit Do

        Dim values = line.Split()
        Dim x1 = Double.Parse(values(0), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Dim y1 = Double.Parse(values(1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Dim x2 = Double.Parse(values(2), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Dim y2 = Double.Parse(values(3), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

        ' do something with these values '

    Loop
End Using
```